# Append file operation in Ada

Tags: file, append, ada

I'm very new to Ada and one thing that I find hard to grasp is working with Files in Ada when it comes to append some values in a file. It seems easier for me to do so in C. Anyway, I haven't found good information and I hope someone could help me here.

I declare the following first:

```
PACKAGE Seq_Float_IO IS NEW Ada.Sequential_IO (Element_Type => Long_Float);
Flo_File : Seq_Long_Float_IO.File_Type;
```

and then I create a file "bvalues.dat":

```
Seq_Long_Float_IO.Create(File => Flo_File, Name => "bvalues.dat");
```

and then to write say a variable named "Largest", I use:

```
Seq_Long_Float_IO.Write(File => Flo_File, Item => Largest);
```

I see that every time I run the code the file "bvalues.dat" gets destroyed and new values are written to it as the program runs. This is ok for me. What I'm doing in my code is to find the largest value of some values and store the largest element in the file "bvalues.dat".

Now say I have to repeat the operation with different sets of values IN THE SAME PROGRAM (say with an outer LOOP) and I need to store the largest element of each set of values. Thus I need to be able to append each largest value of every set to the file "bvalues.dat". How to achieve this?

Do I need to close the file "bvalues.dat" each time after writing a largest value and then open it again:

```
Seq_Long_Float_IO.Open(File => Flo_File, Mode => Append_File, Name => "bvalues.dat");
```

say after an index in an outer loop gets incremented to take in the next set of values for which the largest element is to be computed and then write as I did above

```
Seq_Long_Float_IO.Write(File => Flo_File, Item => Largest);   ?
```

NEW INFO:

I get the error:

```
40.       Seq_Long_Float_IO.Open(File => Flo_File, Mode => Append_File, Name => "bvalues.dat");
                                                      |
    >>> "Append_File" is not visible
    >>> non-visible declaration at a-sequio.ads:58, instance at line 8
    >>> non-visible declaration at a-textio.ads:56
```

Thanks a lot...

---

Test file:

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO;
WITH Ada.Sequential_IO;

PROCEDURE TestWrite5 IS
   PACKAGE Seq_Float_IO IS NEW Ada.Sequential_IO (Element_Type => Float);
   Flo_File : Seq_Float_IO.File_Type;


BEGIN

   Seq_Float_IO.Open (File => Flo_File, Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Append_File,
   Name =>"bvalues.dat");
   exception
   when Name_Error =>
   Create (File => Flo_File, Mode => Out_File, Name => "bvalues.dat");

END TestWrite5;
```

On compiling I get:

12. exception

    13. when Name_Error =>
                |

        > > > "Name_Error" is not visible
        > > >       non-visible declaration at a-sequio.ads:111, instance at line 5
        > > >       non-visible declaration at a-textio.ads:298
        > > >       non-visible declaration at a-ioexce.ads:23
    14. Create (File => Flo_File, Mode => Out_File, Name => "bvalues.dat");
              |

        > > > "Create" is not visible
        > > >       non-visible declaration at a-sequio.ads:73, instance at line 5
        > > >       non-visible declaration at a-textio.ads:90

    15.

It doesn't change if I also put Seq_Float_IO.Out_File instead of just Out_File.

Comment: The compiler error is probably indicating that you need to put the package name in front of that mode. Something like: `Seq_Long_Float_IO.Append_File`. If its not in that package, try one of the ones the error message suggested (Text_IO, Sequential_IO).

Comment: Thanks again. I get Seq_Long_Float_IO.Append_File is undefined.

Comment: How to try the others? I have both Text_IO, Sequential_IO in my preamble. I have also tried: Seq_Long_Float_IO_Text_IO.Open. I don't know much what I'm doing here as I'm new to Ada.

Comment: `Mode => Seq_Long_Float_IO.Append_File` compiles for me ...

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't succeed, See the piece of code at the bottom of my code. It's a minimal example. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I changed Long_Float to Float just to minimize key strokes.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing in your case you need to stick the package name (`Seq_Long_Float_IO.`) on the front of all the routines and objects you are getting from that package. In this case, that would be `Create` and `Open`, and possibly `Name_Error` and `Append_File`. The compiler error messages should be telling you.

Comment: Another alternative of course is to do a `use Seq_Float_IO` to get local visibility to everything from that package. Generally uses are frowned upon, but in the case of the IO packages, it can be overlooked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works if I use Seq_Long_Float_IO before create and name_error in addition to before append_file. And you're right about not using the "use" clause carelessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create, like the name implies, will create a brand new file, even if one already exists.

If the file already exists and you want to append to it, you would use `Open`.

If you want to open it for appending, but if it doesn't exist create it, the normal idiom is to put the `Create` call in an exception handler around `Open`, like so:

```
begin
   Open (File => Flo_File, Mode => Append_File, Name => "bvalues.dat");
exception
   when Name_Error =>
      Create (File => Flo_File, Mode => Out_File, Name => "bvalues.dat");
end;
```

From the rest of your text, it looks like you are thinking about storing temp values in a file. I wouldn't do that unless you need persistence for some reason (recovering from crashes, etc). Disk IO is way *way* **way** slow. Just keep your temp values in a variable and save the result when you have it.

Comment: Thanks. But I still do get the error: Append_File" is not visible (please see the bottom of my post).

Comment: I'm storing results in the file. If I understand you well then I can write each set of values in an array, compute the maximum and then only write the largest value to the file. But I have to do this operation many times as the program will generate one array after the other.

Comment: Yes I agree it takes much CPU resources to open and close each time. I was wondering if I can just open the file once and append as the maximum of each "set" or array of values gets computed.

Comment: Your answer to creating an exception is very good. This way I don't have to "specifically create" the file at the beginning.